# how to check if the cell is blank even if it has formulae

Tags: vba, excel

```
   Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(_
     sht_store.Range(Cells(k, 12), (k, lcol)),_
     "       <>",_
     sht_store.Range(Cells(5, 12), Cells(5, lcol)))
```

I wrote this code to  sum up the values if the cell is nonblank .. However this is not working since the cell may be blank but still might have formulae in it.

I cant change any other code in the module.. Is there any way i can give some other condition so as to sum up the non blanks(instead of "<>") ?

Comment: check isblank function

Answer (score 2):

In VBA you can use

- [`IsEmpty`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-sg/access-help/isempty-function-HA001228864.aspx) for empty cells
- To check if a Cell has formula,

Code:

```
Option Explicit 

Function IsFormula(ByRef wscell As Range) As Boolean 
    IsFormula = wscell.HasFormula 
End Function
```

In Excel you may use

- [`IsBlank`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isblank.php) for empty cells

Thus, in your case check this out:

1. Check if the Cell has a formula
2. Then check if it IsNull, without spaces.

Afterwards you may get going with your `SumIF`. Regardless of the formula, this will return if cell is really empty/null or not.

```
Function izNull(ByRef rng As Range) As Boolean
 If Trim(rng.Value) = "" Then
    izNull = True
 End If
End Function
```

Comment: Using `""` \ `VbNullstring` will count a cell with *`* as empty when it isn't

Comment: @brettdj good point, looking at OP's request I ignored it, since he is ignoring formulas. However in that case, a *OR rng.Value = `* would do?

Comment: I use `vbNullstring` regardless. :) `IsEmpty` does catch it. so perhaps `izNull = IsEmpty(rng)`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with using `.Text` property:

**`Cells([rowindex],[columnindex]).Text = ""`**